# Why there isn't an "Equalable" interface in Java?

Tags: java

The `equals` method of `Object` just compare address:

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {  
    return (this == obj);  
}
```

I think it's not useful in most cases, and we may override it. But for the most Classes I developed, I didn't override the `equals` method, because I won't use it at all...

So I just wonder, why Java language designer put `equals` method in `Object`?
Why there isn't an "Equalable" interface like `Comparable`?

Comment: Even for objects that don't override, knowing that a single object is always equal to itself is thoroughly useful.

Comment: Possibly the designers thought that the default `equals` (and `hashCode`) behaviour was generally usable (people can override it where required), whereas a default `compareTo` implementation would not be generally useful, because there isn't really a natural ordering for general objects.

Comment: 2 things can either be equal or non-equal. they may not be comparable but still that means they are not equal.

Comment: *"because I won't use it at all"* - you don't use any collections in your code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Identity provides a universal definition of equality. Every object is equal to itself. It may or may not be logically equal to some objects that are not itself. If it is, override `equals` and `hashCode`. If not, inherit the `Object` ones.

That is very different from being Comparable. It is possible for a structure that might be represented by a class to lack any meaningful total order - consider the complex numbers.

Answer (score 4):

The `equals()` method is used by the Java system classes, for example in HashMap. Since every object may be stored in HashMap, every object needs an equals() method. The default implementation is sufficient for this.

This is just one example. There are lots of places equals() is called.

Comment: Every object can also be placed in a `TreeMap` - yet, it is not `Comparable` (and an exception will be raised) `Set<Object> s = new TreeSet<>(); s.add(new Object());` will compile just fine

Comment: Having a equals() and hashCode() method in every object was a design decision made years before there was TreeMap.

Comment: @amit HashMaps and Lists are used way more often than TreeMaps. `equals` also has a sane default implementation, where there is none for `compare`. It would be very inconvenient to add boilerplate default `equals` methods to almost every class - or create wrapper for 3rd party classes

Comment: @kapep I criticized the argument of `Since every object may be stored in HashMap, every object needs an equals() method` Boiler plate is a different argument than "you need to support all objects, because every object can be inserted", and the counter example is the Comparable.

Comment: @amit ok I misunderstood. A treeset only accepts all objects because you can also provide a comparator to make it work for non-Comparables though. `equals`-based collections could have done the same by providing a (default) "equality-comparator" (not sure how to name that). But I think it's bad design in the first place, to mix both comparator and comparable approach in the same collection type.

Answer (score 1):

If Java had the interface "Equalable" like the interface "Comparable" it would not be mandatory to include it in every object in Java, so there might arise new problems when adding an object into a Collection and so on.

And of course the hashcode  + equals contract paradigm would be broken

Please check this link from effective Java

http://www.ideyatech.com/2011/04/effective-java-equals-and-hashcode/

Comment: The same applies to comparable. `Set<Object> s = new TreeSet<>(); s.add(new Object());` will compile just fine, but throw an exception.

Comment: @amit But then you would have to use custom "equalators" when creating every collection.